# NY Steak vs NY Strip Steak

Tags: steak

My local grocery store (Fred Meyer/Kroger) has NY Steak in the clearance section today, (it's going out of date soon.) What I can't seem to find is whether the NY Steak is the same as a NY Strip Steak which you find at all of the top steak houses. (These steaks are bone-in, with a little bit of bone in the tip.)

Are these the same as NY Strip Steaks, or am I paying too much for a worse cut of meat by buying them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same cut of beef. Depending on the butcher it may or may not be 'trimmed' a little differently. A New York strip is cut from the sirloin primal, specifically the 'top loin'. If one looks at a typical T-bone (or Porterhouse) steak the 'larger side' of the steak (to one-side of the bone) becomes a strip steak once cut from the bone. After that the way it is trimmed and prepared makes the difference between New York and Kansas City strip steaks, but these too are the same basic cut of beef.